# Grelka. Light of my life. Fire of my loins. My sin, My soul. Why the hell won't you marry me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Grelka is a comely nord lass from the city of Riften. She dreams of leaving Skyrim, demands your money in the gruffest manner possible, sells and offers training in the use of Light Armor, buys a variety of legitimate, and with a properly honeyed tongue, illegitimate goods at a fair price (certainly better than that churl of a blacksmith Balimund. He offers to marry me daily. I guess Skyrim is pretty progressive like that). Oh, and by Skyrim standards, she's gorgeous. Skyrim standards aren't terribly high in this regard.

[image: Grelka]

According to Prima's official strategy guide, as well as [UESP,](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Grelka) and [The Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Grelka), she is an eligible Bachelorette (and what a catch!). She's a member of the `PotentialMarriageFaction`, but no matter what I say to her, no matter how many of her goods I buy, no matter what valuable gifts I secretly deposit in her pockets, she refuses to acknowledge my Amulet of Mara.

The heartless woman just will not marry me.

How can I win Grelka's love and devotion for all eternity? How can I make her mine?

(Alternately, how can I get her to agree to a marriage of convenience, secure in the knowledge that my imminent death will award her an inheritance of the sort the emperor could only dream? I'm not really *that* picky here.)

Comment: "Girl's don't like boys, girl like items and money"

Comment: @Domocus But I've given her money! And items! And she still doesn't like me! And who said my Dovahkin was a boy anyway? (Oh wait, I kind of implied that, didn't I.)

Comment: Maybe that's your answer - she might have her cold, cold heart set on a Dovakinette...although I doubt the marriage system is that sophisticated...

Comment: @artless It's not. I know that much. Love in Skyrim is blind. And also kind of stupid.

Comment: What team does she play for?

Comment: It's possible that she's quest relevant for something and she won't marry you until you find that quest (Thieves guild, perhaps?) and complete it.

Comment: @raven: she's not as near as I can tell, and I've been researching this *extensively*. I'd love to be proven wrong though.

Comment: This just got tweeted by the Twitter account...I had to read this.

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but, you are wearing the amulet, right? It's not just sitting in your inventory? I've unequipped things without realizing it before...only later, when someone was kind enough to yell at me for not wearing clothes, did I realize the error of my ways...

Comment: Yes. It is a silly question. Yes, yes I am wearing it. (I did not that Balimund propositions me non stop while I am en route to court my sweet Grelka, did I not?)

Comment: With that much snark I wouldn't marry you either ;P. I'm inclined to agree with the bug answer, then. I mean, I know Elder Scrolls games never have bugs, but maybe the alignment of the planets is off this week.

Comment: Never played Skyrim, but girl named Grelka really amuses me. In Russian `grelka` means "[hot water bottle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6ELVA.jpg)" (or heating pad).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> According to some [sources](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Grelka), Grelka is supposed to be available to the player as a potential spouse after the amulet of Mara has been acquired, but a bug prevents the dialogue option from opening, possibly due to a removed or bugged quest. This can be solved on the PC by targeting her in the console and using the command "addtofaction 19809 1", as well as the code "setrelationshiprank player 4 " which will open up the option for marriage. However, this is done at the player's own risk.
>
> With 1.3 patch, the bug still needs fixing, but only typing "**setrelationshiprank player 2**" on her will do the trick.

This should enable the marriage dialogue options.

Answer (score 8):

I've been scouring the internet trying to find out how to marry her - with no luck. other people are having the same issue. To give more details: Yes, the amulet is being used. Yes, it is a working version (I can ask my housecarl next to me to wed). Yes, we've completed ALL of the Mara quests. Completed most if not all Riften quests - including being Thane. I even completed the Dibella quest to become an Agent of Dibella which apparently "allows you to woo the opposite sex" Completed thieves guild. Nothing works. Even adding her via the console to the "marriage" faction - which works on other people, whos quests you haven't completed yet - fails to work. Most likely? It's either bugged, or they removed her as an option because she's a trainer and a vendor. Or they just removed her.

Possible leads: When searching for "Grelka" in the console, an item called "package for grelka" is revealed. I have not been able to find out where this item is, if there's a quest for it, etc. I think it's most likely left over files from when she WAS an option but nolonger is, since she doesn't give the quest. But, it's possible it's an item you find somewhere to give to her, I guess.

Hope this helps. Well, it doesn't, but maybe it'll save some time googling around.

Comment: Adding her to the Marriage faction doesn't work because she's *already* a member of it. The problem is that there's a missing trigger -  presumably the package for her.

Comment: Actually i'm pretty sure this is not the case. There's 3 states to the "marriage" faction. -1 is unmarrigable, 0 is marriageable but you can't yet, and 1 is marriageable and ready I've been setting it to 1. I'm pretty sure this is the case because it worked for Lydia for me, who I could not yet marry otherwise.